# How do I bootstrap correlations between two data frames?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, correlation, statistics-bootstrap, mclapply

I have not been able to find an example of bootstrapping correlations between two data frames. Key posts I have looked at are
(1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/computing-p-value-using-bootstrap-with-r/
(2) [How to bootstrap correlation using vectorised function applied to large matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270243/how-to-bootstrap-correlation-using-vectorised-function-applied-to-large-matrix)

NB/ p values here need to be obtained through calculating the ratios of how many times the absolute bootstrap test statistics exceeded the theoretical ones,

Fortunately, I have also come across a recent example of using Map to apply the correlations between two data frames.
[How to use lapply to replace nested for loop to get correlations between two data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77294650/how-to-use-lapply-to-replace-nested-for-loop-to-get-correlations-between-two-dat/77295864?noredirect=1#comment136270376_77295864)

I have large datasets that will be run in a unix based HPC and also a Windows OS option for running the calculations on smaller datasets in R.

```
   D1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*10, 0, 2), ncol=10)) 
   D2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*16, 0, 2), ncol=16)) 

   colnames(D1) <- paste0("a", 1:ncol(D1))
   colnames(D2) <- paste0("b", 1:ncol(D2))

   compare <- expand.grid(colnames(D1), colnames(D2))

  need_modify <- Map(function(x,y) cor.test(D1[, x], D2[, y], method="spearman"), compare$Var1,    compare$Var2) %>% 
  lapply(`[`, c('estimate', 'statistic', 'p.value')) %>% 
  sapply(unlist) %>%  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% mutate(Var1=compare$Var1, Var2=compare$Var2)

  boot_df <- function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), rep = T), ]

 #number of bootstraps 
 R <- 100
```

I am stuck on modifying the above so that it run successfully using parallelisation for Unix based OS (mclapply or mcMap) and also a separate one for Windows (clusterMap or future_mapply).

Grateful for any pointers in the right direction or an example elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you could resample *B* times with replacement, extract the `"statistic"`s,

```
stopifnot(identical(dim(D1)[1], dim(D2)[1]))  ## check identical nrows
r.names <- Reduce(\(...) paste(..., sep=':'), Cmp)  ## store Cmp names

ncpu <- 7L  ## number of workers
B <- 999L  ## number of bootstrap replications
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
T_star <- parallel::mcmapply(function(x, y) {
  boot <- function() {  ## boot fun
    smp <- sample.int(dim(D1)[1], dim(D1)[1],  ## resample w/ replacement
                      replace=TRUE)
    unlist(cor.test(D1[smp, x], D2[smp, y], method="spearman", exact=FALSE)[
      c('statistic')])  ## extract statistic
  }
  replicate(B, boot())  ## replicate boot fun B times
}, Cmp$Var1, Cmp$Var2, mc.cores=ncpu, mc.set.seed=FALSE, SIMPLIFY=FALSE) |> setNames(r.names)

lapply(T_star, head)[1:3]
# $`a1:b1`
# statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S 
#    212.4375    208.3125    205.7407    278.1132    216.5625    233.5714 
# 
# $`a2:b1`
# statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S 
#   270.18750   195.93750   258.70370   130.75472   216.56250    77.14286 
# 
# $`a3:b1`
# statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S statistic.S 
#    144.3750    270.1875    220.0000    220.0000    198.0000    158.5714
```

and according to Davison & Hinkley ([1997](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802843))'s formula,

[image]

calculate a Monte Carlo P-value add up how many times the actual statistic,

```
T_act <- parallel::mcmapply(\(x, y) cor.test(D1[, x], D2[, y], meth='s'), 
                          Cmp$Var1, Cmp$Var2, mc.cores=ncpu, SIMPLIFY=FALSE) |>
  lapply(`[[`, c('statistic')) |> 
  sapply(unlist) |> setNames(r.names)
T_act[1:3]
# a1:b1 a2:b1 a3:b1 
#   210   156   232
```

is exceeded divided by *B* (using a bias correction by adding `+1` to both, the numerator and denominator).

```
p_values <- parallel::mcmapply(\(x, y) (sum(abs(x) >= abs(y)) + 1)/(B + 1), 
                               T_star, T_act, mc.cores=ncpu) |>
  setNames(r.names) |> unlist()

p_values[1:3]
# a1:b1 a2:b1 a3:b1 
# 0.507 0.477 0.490
```

**Of course, we can combine everything and simplify to:**

```
ncpu <- 7L  ## number of workers
B <- 999L  ## number of bootstrap replications
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
p_values2 <- parallel::mcmapply(\(x, y) {
  boot <- \() {  ## boot fun
    smp <- sample.int(dim(D1)[1], dim(D1)[1],  ## resample w/ replacement
                      replace=TRUE)
    unlist(cor.test(D1[smp, x], D2[smp, y], method="spearman", exact=FALSE)[
      c('statistic')])  ## extract statistic
  }
  t_star <- replicate(B, boot())  ## replicate boot fun B times
  t_act <- unlist(cor.test(D1[, x], D2[, y], method="spearman", exact=FALSE)[
    c('statistic')])
  (sum(abs(t_star) >= abs(t_act)) + 1)/(B + 1)  ## calc. MC p-value
}, Cmp$Var1, Cmp$Var2, mc.cores=ncpu, mc.set.seed=FALSE) |> unlist() |> 
  setNames(r.names)

head(p_values2, 3)
# a1:b1 a2:b1 a3:b1 
# 0.507 0.477 0.490
```

**Note,** that the answer focuses on how to do it **technically**. Read Davison & Hinkley ([1997](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511802843)) or consult a statistician if you really want it to be sound.

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
D1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*10, 0, 2), ncol=10)) |> 
  setNames(paste0("a", seq_len(10)))
D2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10*16, 0, 2), ncol=16)) |> 
  setNames(paste0("b", seq_len(16)))
Cmp <- expand.grid(colnames(D1), colnames(D2))
```

Comment: very helpful - much appreciated, thank you! Just to check, to modify this for a Windows OS, I would need to use the clusterMap , specifying the cluster and using clusterexport etc

Comment: You're welcome @Upstream258. Yes, `parallel::clusterMap`, `parallel::clusterExport` (good luck with finding all the objects you need in the clusters), maybe `parallel::clusterEvalQ`, and `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream` for setting the seed.

Comment: @jay.sf was wondering what the null hypothesis would be here? I'm not sure if the calculation of p values in this example would be valid if wanting to check the null hypothesis of there is no difference between the test using the original data vs that of the bootstrapped data -perhaps permutation might be more suitable for me. I can't access the book unfortunately (behind paywall).

Comment: @pemb_bex6789 The approach I've shown is resampling the data [in pairs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59764/163114).  Davison & Hinkley refer to a so-called _pivot test_ , where "we do not have to construct a special null hypothesis sampling distribution." [This Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/604378/163114) might be relevant to that. My uncertainty relates to this; we do not divide the bootstrap differences from the original sample estimate by the bootstrap standard error (which might be possible using pearson), but use only z_0.

Comment: @jay.sf is there a reason as to why some of my bootstrap correlations have NA for each of the estimate, statistic etc? I was getting NA for some of the p values, so delved in and saw that for some of the bootstrap calculations there are NA , but others have values. I've checked for any scientific notation etc that could be affecting it but wasn't sure why this might arise...

Comment: @Upstream258 you're not really correlating standard normal, are you?

Comment: @Upstream258 Don't really get what you're doing, but sometimes simulation is complicated. I suggest to add the `.Random.seed` as an `\`attr<-\`()`ibute for each iteration. So, if an iteration fails, you can reproduce it and check the issue.